# Django server connection error with Docker Toolbox in OS X Yosemite

Tags: django, docker, networking, django-rest-framework, docker-compose

I run the following yml file with `$docker-compose up` command. I'm developing a REST API with django (Udemy "Build a Backend REST API with Python & Django - Advanced").

- System: OS X 10.10.5
- Docker version: 18.03.0-ce
- docker-compose version: 1.20.1

**Q: I am unable to access localhost with 127.0.0.1**

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "2.2"
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./app:/app
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py wait_for_db && 
             python manage.py migrate &&
             python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    environment:
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=app
      - DB_USER=postgres
      - DB_PASS=supersecretpassword
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres:10-alpine
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=app
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=supersecretpassword
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

#python unbuffered environmental variable
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

#copy requirements.txt from the directory adjacent to
#the Dockerfile into dockerimage/requirments.txt
COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add --update --no-cache postgresql-client
RUN apk add --update --no-cache --virtual .tmp-build-deps \
        gcc libc-dev linux-headers postgresql-dev
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt
RUN apk del .tmp-build-deps

#create an empty folder named app in docker image
RUN mkdir /app 
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./app /app

RUN adduser -D user
USER user
```

> Some suggest to add CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver",
>   "0.0.0.0:8000"] in Dockerfile; didn't work in this case. In django
>   settings.py, ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['192.168.99.100']

**Console output (part of: see bold)**

> ---
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py",
>
> ---
>
> line 178, in get_new_connection connection = Database.connect(conn_params)
>
> ---
>
> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/psycopg2/**init**.py",
>
> ---
>
> line 130, in connect conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, kwasync)
>   **django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused**
>
> ---
>
> **
>   Is the server running on host "db" (172.19.0.2) and accepting
>   TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

I'm super new to this stuff, appreciate your help and suggestions.

Comment: try `ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']`

Comment: Also please post how you are starting the server? On which Port?

Comment: I tried ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*'], didn't help. In the docker-compse file, ports are defined as for the app 8000:8000 and for the db port is the default (5432)

Comment: My guess is that your instance starts much faster than the DB.

One thing that should make it work: use restart: unless-stopped on your app service.

It will keep running again the app until it's connected.

Like this: 

app:
    build:
      context: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    [...]

Comment: @FábioCorreia, to prevent instance starting before db, I am calling 'python manage.py wait_for_db' .

Comment: Got it, then probably your only problem is with networking!

You did not state any network to say: "Hey, I am here too!" by using "db" as host.

Try using networks like this:

app:
  [...]
  networks:
    - my_network
db:
  [...]
  networks:
    - my_network

networks:
  my_network: (it will default to bridge network)

This way, you will have service discovery for both apps as it's names :)

Comment: Oh, if you do not want to use networks, you may use also the flag: links

Docker Docs:

Networks: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#networks

Links: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#links

Comment: I researched about this issue last 2 weeks, and I assumed that this is a container networking issue. But, I was not sure about it. I wanted to hear from someone with experience in docker and django.

Comment: @MaheshImaduwa Can you please provide Dockerfile and/or any reference to source code. Thanks.

Comment: @mariodev, I added the Dockerfile. git repo https://github.com/mwickram/recipe-app-api

Comment: @MaheshImaduwa Thanks. I built the docker and can access the webapp just fine. Maybe something is blocking the db instance from running? Port conflicts? Is there anything else in the logs that you can spot? Certainly smth wrong with your host config..

Comment: @mariodev, those who ran this Dockerfile and docker-compose with "Docker Toolbox" (legacy) in OS X Yosemite have experienced this problem; probably a problem related to container networking.

Comment: Sent you a pull request that might help you with this container connection issue :)